# Display not changing from "none" to "block" when hovering on image in table

Tags: html, css, hover

Title pretty much says it all. I basically want to hover on the image and have the name fade in at the bottom like a caption. Only it's not doing that.

Here's the code: https://jsfiddle.net/Ltb8a7cc/

This is the css in question:

```
    .productIconName {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #158538;
  animation: fadein 500ms;
  display: none;
}

    .productIconImage:hover ~ .productIconName {
  display: block;
}
```

And the html of the second row which doesn't show the text on hover:

```
    <td class=productIconName>
    Name
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work if you put `.productIconName` in the same td element as `.productIconImage`.

```css
    .productIconImage {
      width: 150px;
      border: solid;
      border-radius: 3px;
      border-color: #F1F1F1;
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: border 500ms ease-out
    }
    
    .productIconName {
      text-align: center;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #158538;
      animation: fadein 500ms;
      display: none;
    }
    
    @keyframes fadein {
      from {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      to {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
    
    .productIconImage:hover {
      border-color: #C3C3C3;
    }
    
    .productIconImage:hover ~ .productIconName {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<table style=width:100%;>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src=https://athlonecommunityradio.ie/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/placeholder.png class=productIconImage>
      <div class=productIconName>
        Name
      </div>
    <td>
      <img src=https://athlonecommunityradio.ie/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/placeholder.png class=productIconImage>
      <div class=productIconName>
        Name
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src=https://athlonecommunityradio.ie/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/placeholder.png class=productIconImage>
      <div class=productIconName>
        Name
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src=https://athlonecommunityradio.ie/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/placeholder.png class=productIconImage>
      <div class=productIconName>
        Name
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you use display the images will jump around when the caption becomes visible. If you use opacity instead of display, they won't jump and you can replace the animation with just a transition.

```css
    .productIconImage {
      width: 150px;
      border: solid;
      border-radius: 3px;
      border-color: #F1F1F1;
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: border 500ms ease-out
    }
    
    .productIconName {
      text-align: center;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #158538;
      transition: 500ms;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    
    .productIconImage:hover {
      border-color: #C3C3C3;
    }
    
    .productIconImage:hover ~ .productIconName {
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
<table style=width:100%;>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src=https://athlonecommunityradio.ie/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/placeholder.png class=productIconImage>
      <div class=productIconName>
        Name
      </div>
    <td>
      <img src=https://athlonecommunityradio.ie/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/placeholder.png class=productIconImage>
      <div class=productIconName>
        Name
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src=https://athlonecommunityradio.ie/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/placeholder.png class=productIconImage>
      <div class=productIconName>
        Name
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src=https://athlonecommunityradio.ie/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/placeholder.png class=productIconImage>
      <div class=productIconName>
        Name
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```